# Framed manifolds question

Tags: differential-topology

Let a $\pi$-manifold be a manifold with the property that its normal bundle is trivial if it is embedded into $\mathbb R^n$ for large enough $n$.

Homotopy spheres are $\pi$-manifolds.

[Here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/framed+manifold) it is stated that the only spheres that admit a framing are $S^1, S^3, S^7$. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold#Remarks) it is stated that a framed manifold is a manifold with trivial normal bundle (therefore the same as a $\pi$-manifold).

These statements contradict each other. Which of the statements is wrong?

Comment: It seems like "framing" is used in a few related but not identical senses.

Comment: The Wikipedia page does not say that a framed manifold is a manifold admitting a framing though. :) The notion discussed on ncat is the same as what Wikipedia calls parallelizability. The ncat page seems to have forgotten $S^0$ though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Framing» means a trivialization of some vector bundle (tangent / stable tangent / normal for some embedding / stable normal). Naturally, existence of a framing depends on what bundle we're talking about.

Pages you're linking to explicitly state that

> **In one sense of the term**, a framing of a manifold is a choice of trivialization of its **tangent bundle**

and

> The term framed manifold (...) is most **usually** applied to an embedded manifold with a given trivialisation of the **normal bundle**